# how to tokenize a string in arduino

Tags: arduino, tokenize

i am using arduino due. what i am trying to do is to receive a string at serial. like this one:
COMSTEP  789 665 432 END
if the string starts with comstep, then to tokenize the string and get an integer array {789, 665, 432}.
is there anyway to do that?
P.S: im a noob at programming, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-do-i-split-an-incoming-string

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that I wrote long ago to parse strings up in an easy manner. It is in use on several of my Arduino projects.

Sample usage:

```
   char pinStr[3];
   char valueStr[7];
   int pinNumber, value;

   getstrfld (parms_in, 0, 0, (char *)",", pinStr);
   getstrfld (parms_in, 1, 0, (char *)",", valueStr);
   pinNumber = atoi (pinStr);
   value = atoi (valueStr);
```

The functions:

```
// My old stand-by to break delimited strings up.
char * getstrfld (char *strbuf, int fldno, int ofset, char *sep, char *retstr)
{
   char *offset, *strptr;
   int curfld;

   offset = strptr = (char *)NULL;
   curfld = 0;

   strbuf += ofset;

   while (*strbuf) {
       strptr = !offset ? strbuf : offset;
       offset = strpbrk ((!offset ? strbuf : offset), sep);

       if (offset) {
          offset++;
       } else if (curfld != fldno) {
          *retstr = 0;
          break;
       }

       if (curfld == fldno) {
           strncpy (retstr, strptr,
              (int)(!offset ? strlen (strptr)+ 1 :
              (int)(offset - strptr)));
           if (offset)
              retstr[offset - strptr - 1] = 0;

           break;
       }

       curfld++;
   }

   return retstr;
}

// Included because strpbrk is not in the arduino gcc/g++ libraries
// Or I just could not find it :)
char * strpbrk (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
   const  char *c = s2;
   if (!*s1) {
      return (char *) NULL;
   }

   while (*s1) {
      for (c = s2; *c; c++) {
          if (*s1 == *c)
              break;
      }
      if (*c)
          break;
      s1++;
   }

   if (*c == '\0')
      s1 = NULL;

   return (char *) s1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A light-weight approach (no strict checks on valid parses of the integers and ignoring any list elements past a fixed maximum):

```
char buf[32] = "COMSTEP 789 665 432 END"; // assume this has just been read
int res[8], nres = 0;
bool inlist = false;

for (char *p = strtok(buf, " "); p; p = strtok(0, " "))
    if (inlist)
    {
        if (!strcmp(p, "END"))
        {
            inlist = false;
            break;
        }
        else if (nres < sizeof(res) / sizeof(*res))
            res[nres++] = atoi(p);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(p, "COMSTEP"))
        inlist = true;

if (!inlist)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nres; ++i)
        printf("%d%s", res[i], i + 1 < nres ? " " : "\n"); // do whatever
```